# How to split a node in a linked list say into chunks of 8 byte?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, linked-list, malloc

Considering I have a 4MB node (as a complete linked list which has just one node), how can I divide my node into smaller chunks (nodes) each having just 8 byte?

```
head = (list_t*) ptr;
head->size = 4MB;
head->next = NULL;
```

P.S.: I am trying to implement malloc on my own that's why I am trying to initialize a memory using linked list.

Comment: `C` or `C++` ? choose one

Answer (score 3):

You want to take offsets successively 8 bytes further into it using pointer arithmetic like this:

```
list_t *next;    
next = head + 1; /* Note that this implicitly means "1 * sizeof(list_t)" */
next->size = head->size - sizeof(list_t);
next->next = NULL;
head->next = next;
```

I can post a more detailed example if you're still stuck.

Are you writing a linked list that manages its own memory (in which case you probably want a data pointer as well), or a memory manager using a linked list (in which case you probably want it to allocate a bit more memory than it uses itself ;-))?